# JS Pebble Kit: parsing an integer value 2, is interpretted as 536999434 by the watchapp

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I have the following code that I send messages  to my pebble watchapp, from the js in the phone. this is with sdk2.

```
Pebble.sendAppMessage({note_id:json[count].note_id,
title:json[count].title,
text:json[count].text,
total_count: count
});
```

I can console.log() the total_count property in the JS when I run the app, and it rightly gets the count , like 2.

Yet, in my pebble app, when I try to extract it in the `in_received_handler` function, the APP LOG in the code below prints out 536999434.

```
Tuple *total_count_tuple = dict_find(iter, TOTAL_COUNT_KEY);

if (total_count_tuple) {
    current_count = (int)total_count_tuple->value->cstring;
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "In in_received_handler, total count     %u",current_count);

}
```

It is getting a count, so I know the dictionary is being filled out and sent over to the watch, but I can't figure out how to get the value that I store in the js to be the same on the pebble side.

Any experienced pebble programmers have a thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending an integer so to read it you need to use:

```
current_count = total_count_tuple->value->int32;
```

instead of:

```
current_count = (int)total_count_tuple->value->cstring;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly the issue, I was trying to convert a c string to an int, but I didn't realize int32 existed, thanks, you saved me a lot of trouble